# XSL filter one column and then count values in another column

Tags: xslt, filter, count

I have a SharePoint list with job information. I am trying to filter a column called **ORGANISATION** for the value **Infrastructure**. There is another column in the list called **JOB STATUS** which has values of **Open**, **Offer** or **Filled**. So i firstly filter for all the Infrastructure records, then i need to count the number of open roles, offered roles and filled roles for it.

SAMPLE DATA

```
ORGANISATION   |   JOBSTATUS
______________________________
Infrastructure |     FILLED
Infrastructure |     OPEN
Business       |     OFFER
Infrastructure |     OPEN
Business       |     FILLED
Infrastructure |     OPEN
Business       |     OPEN
```

CODE

```
<tr><th>ORGANISATION</th><th>OPEN</th><th>OFFER</th><th>FILLED</th></tr>

<tr>
<td>Infrastructure Services</td>
<td><xsl:variable name="OPEN">
       <xsl:for-each select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[(normalize-space(@Title)='Infrastructure')]">                                                                                        
          <xsl:value-of select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[(normalize-space(@JobStatus)='OPEN')])"/>                                                   
       </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="$OPEN"/>
</td>

<td>Offer Code</td><td>Filled Code</td></tr>
```

The total number of open roles is 44. The number of open roles in infrastructure is 8. The above code is returning 44 but i need it to return 8. Can anyone see where i am going wrong?

Comment: Can you please post input data and a screenshot of output along with question to make me understand it better

Comment: @UmairM added a small snippet of how the list looks, does this clarify it any better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `for-each` just use

```
 <xsl:value-of select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[(normalize-space(@Title)='Infrastructure') and (normalize-space(@JobStatus)='OPEN')])"/>
```

This might give you what you want. Let me know if its helpful :)

Comment: Tried this before hand but was getting an error on the page, however, whatever i (you) have done this time has worked so thanks for your help !